# Installing programs on local disk D

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I switched from windows to Ubuntu yesterday and I'm just starting. I had two partitions on windows as it's normal there and I left as it was. I want to install software on Local Disk :D, not C, but I have no idea about the solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

On Linux (and Unix in general) you do not have drive letters.

You have a root, `/`, with everything under the root.

For instance a lot of software goes into `/usr/`, while your user owned files goes into `/home/username/`, configuration files in `/etc/` and so forth.

Any directory may be a mount point, so yo can have one partition for `/usr`, one for `/`, and one for `/home`. But I wouldn't recommend that for a newbie, as it easily ends up with a lot of wasted disk space.

What I would suggest is to have one partition for `/` and one for `/home`. This way you can keep all your personal files across upgrades or reinstalls easily.

The windows model doesn't apply at *all* to Unix in general. So forget what you know about partitioning from Windows, and run with one partition (~50-100GB) for `/` and one for `/home` (the rest of the disk).

Note that you have probably not kept the disk partitions from Windows, as Ubuntu will probably not install to a NTFS disk.